# How to unwrap and apply tileable texture on a cone?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I tried distorting a texture to polar coordinates and apply on cone shape and scaling the the uv and I got like in the pic, How to unwrap and use tileable texture on cone properly with scaling the amount of bricks as in reference image below? or should I generate different kind of texture for this?

[image]

Comment: Houw does your final image should look like? do you have a reference?

Comment: Yes I have included now.

Comment: the pattern is repeating because the UV is bigger than the image, first give a try with the correct size (scale down the UV in the UV Editor)

Comment: Ya, scaling down gives me less number of bricks , I want large number of bricks around the cone like tileable. for example in normal brick texture  if we scale up we get large number of bricks, right.

Comment: in that case your image is not good for this purpose; you can either keep the same principle (concentric pattern) but you need to make it larger, or create a orthogonal pattern and unwrap in another way, like cylinder or active quad

Comment: If you press <kbd> 1</kbd> for front view and select the *Cylinder Projection* that is one way to do it.

Comment: Realted https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210632/2214

Answer (score 0):

IMO, if you can afford them, geometric tiles, (or a baked derivation from them) are probably a good idea.

But if we're answering the question:'How to UV map a cone with even-sized, undistorted tiles?', then some variation on this might go some way to answering.

You could start with a *Cylindrical Projection* unwrap of your all-quad, (slightly truncated) cone. For convenience, the resulting rectangle should fill the whole 0-1 UV space.

In order to get the same-width tiles at the top as at the bottom of your cone, the UV has to be scaled in U as a function of V. But that would distort them. So, instead, you could arrange a step-wise scale, concealing the steps in the mortar:

[image]

The steps in the *Map Range* will be the overall *Brick* scale, -1.

You can tweak the initial *Multiply* of X and the *Brick* offset, to make the overlaps as pleasing as possible, and  minimize the visibility of the UV seam.

[image]

Comment: So timely.  I need this for a project that I'm not at all happy with for exactly this issue

Comment: Thanks, @AllenSimpson!. I was wondering about all the jiggery-pokery necessary to get rid of the seam, have overlapping tiles, etc... but that's not really the OP's question, I think?... it's a from-scratch procedural texture.